# what is the best way to reuse API manager class and store data so that it is reusable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class

I have a PageViewController which creates instances of DataViewController, and this dataViewController needs to do some API called (from manager Class) then use that data to populate its UI. I.E. a page is added, the dataViewController gets its datasource and uses that to tell the API what to get.

The problem is, as I can add multiple pages, and I need for example data to form a graph for each page, having to do the API call every time the view controller loads I feel is unness esary, and that there must be a better way to store the data for the life of the session once it have been retrieved. as each instance of dataViewController uses the same API Managers, I refresh them clearing any data they have, and start the API call again for the page that loaded, this can sometimes get data mixed up, displaying a mixture of information from two pages or displaying the wrong data on the wrong page. Here is an example of one of my API managers which uses the dataObject of the dataViewController to get chart data:

```
import Foundation

struct Root: Codable {
let prices: [Price]
}
struct Price: Codable {
let date: Date
let price: Double
}

class CGCharts {

var priceData = [Price]()
var graphPrices: [Double] = []
var graphTimes: [String] = []

static let shared = CGCharts()

var defaultCurrency = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DefaultCurrency")!

var coin = ""
var currency = ""
var days = ""

    enum GraphStatus {
    case day, week, month
}

    var graphSetup = GraphStatus.day

    func getData(arr: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    switch graphSetup {

    case .day:
        days = "1"
    case .week:
        days = "14"
    case .month:
        days = "30"

    }

    let urlJSON = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/\(coin)/market_chart?vs_currency=\(defaultCurrency)&days=\(days)"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlJSON) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let prices = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data).prices
            print(prices.first!.date.description(with:.current))  // "Saturday, September 1, 2018 at 6:25:38 PM Brasilia Standard Time\n"
            print(prices[0].price)
            self.priceData = prices

            for element in prices {
                self.graphPrices.append(element.price)
            }
            for element in prices {
                self.graphTimes.append(element.date.description(with: nil))

            }

            completion(arr)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()

}

func refresh(arr: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    defaultCurrency = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DefaultCurrency")!
    graphPrices = []
    graphTimes = []


    completion(arr)
}

}
```

Here as you can see I am getting the data, using codable to parse and in this case the best way I could find to seperate the data was to use the two arrays, I basically want to have thoes 2 arrays stored in memory for that specific dataObject, so that when a page with the same dataObject loads in the pageView it will first check if that data already exists, and use that, instead of getting new information everytime and me having to clear the class. Hope I am making sense, Thank you.

Comment: You can create a custom class and use NSCache to cache them in memory for the life of the user session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching more about NSCache, I learned you can save data to the disk or cache and access it again easily. I found this excellent storage class made by Saoud M. Rizwan [here](https://medium.com/@sdrzn/swift-4-codable-lets-make-things-even-easier-c793b6cf29e1)

which makes it super easy to store structs:

```
var messages = [Message]()

for i in 1...4 {
let newMessage = Message(title: "Message \(i)", body: "...")
messages.append(newMessage)
}

Storage.store(messages, to: .documents, as: "messages.json")
```

and retrieve them:

```
let messagesFromDisk = Storage.retrieve("messages.json", from: .documents, as: [Message].self)
```

Perfect for storing data from an API so that you don't have to make so many API calls, which is especially useful if your requests are limited. In my case, I use the method for checking if storage exists, and if it does I use that to load my data, and if not then I do an api call, store the data using this class, and then run the check again to see that the data is there and use that, It may not be the most efficient but it works.

my example:

```
var prices: [Double] = []
var days: [String] = []
var priceData = [Price]()

var graphDataExists = false
func checkGraphStorage() {
    if Storage.fileExists("\(dataObject)GraphPrices", in: 
Storage.Directory.caches) {
        print("UsingSavedData")
        self.priceData = Storage.retrieve("\(dataObject)GraphPrices", from: 
Storage.Directory.caches, as: [Price].self)

        if self.prices.isEmpty {
        for element in self.priceData {
            self.prices.append(element.price)
        }
        for element in self.priceData {
            self.days.append(element.date.description(with: nil))
            graphDataExists = true

        }
        } else {

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 4.0)
            self.lineChartUpdate(dataPoints: self.days, values: self.prices)
        }


    } else {
        self.prepareGraph(arr: true) { (success) in

        }

    }
}
```